# Cannot run project app (Gradle Build Failed)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

today I updated my Android Studio to 2.2.. I'm not sure this is because of update but I got this error when I run the app

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug'.
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.DescriptiveChange cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.InputFileDetails
ay be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 7.336 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I was trying to clean and rebuild app but there was nothing affect

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Delete .gradle folder then clean and run... maybe it'll help for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

1. Close Android Studio, if it's opened
2. Go to the project workspace (Eg: C:\wheverever\it\is\TheProjectName)
3. Delete **.gradle** folder
4. Open Android Studio. **Clean and build** your project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have deleted it but It doesn't give any changes.. I still get an error like that

Comment: the gradle fails to build any app or just this one?

Comment: It happens just on this app only